# Caliburn.micro get treeview's selected item by contextmenu onclick

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, contextmenu, caliburn.micro

I have a task to use a contextmenu in treeview and pass selected treeview's item to ViewModel by clicking on contextmenu element.

Here is my xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Ufps"
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
........
........
<TreeView x:Name="TrvUfpsDictionary" Height="222" Canvas.Left="25" 
  Canvas.Top="280" Width="545"
  Background="AliceBlue" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ufps, Mode=OneWay}" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Ufps}">
        <TreeView.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Add Element"
             cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action AddElement(TrvUfpsDictionary.SelectedItem)]"
                />
                ................
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.ContextMenu>           
    </TreeView>
........
<Button Content="Test" Canvas.Left="475" Canvas.Top="568" Width="75"
 cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action AddElement(TrvUfpsDictionary.SelectedItem)]"/>
```

And here is simple ViewModel's code:

```
  public class UserSettingsViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
  {
   ..........

   public void AddElement(object selectedItem)
    {         
       MessageBox.Show("Element added! "+selectedItem.?GetHashCode());            
    }
   ..........
  }
```

Now I've stuck with it. When I've selected treeview's item and then I've pressed the "Test" button - it works fine, it pass the selected item to "AddElement" in my VM. BUT when I do the same with contextmenu - it always pass null. Did I miss something?

EDIT
I've made a simple app with the problem described. https://github.com/whizzzkey/WpfApp1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to move the Context Menu further into the TreeView, into the Item Template and add Context Menu to the Label/TextBlock you have in nodes.

For example, consider the following Employee tree (emulating since I do not know your data structure),

```xml
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}" >
        <Label Content="{Binding DepartmentName}"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" >
                <Label Content="{Binding PositionName}"
                    Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=TestControl}" >
                    <Label.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu
                            cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Add Element"
                                cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action AddElement($datacontext)]"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Label.ContextMenu>
                </Label>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding EmployeeName}"
                            Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=TestControl}">
                            <Label.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu
                                    cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                    <MenuItem Header="Add Element"
                                        cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action AddElement($datacontext)]" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Label.ContextMenu>
                        </Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

There are couple of important points to note here. Since your method exists in ViewModel and you have to ensure that the DataContext is pointing to your ViewModel instead of the Item Type that is bound to node.

For this, you need can make use of `cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext`. The following line the Label definition ensure we have access to the View's DataContext.

```
Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=TestControl}"
```

While the following line ensures the we get our bindings right (to ViewModel). `TestControl` is the x:Name for your UserControl

```
cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Finally the Click Action would be modified as following.

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action AddElement($datacontext)]"
```

This would ensure your ViewModel's Action is called with the right parameter passed.

**Update**

Based on your comment and code,following are the changes required.

**Window Definition** : Add x:Name

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    Title="XmlData Tree Test"
    x:Name="TestControl"
    Width="250"
    Height="350">
```

**Root Hierarchical Template**
Associating Item source with Tag is placed on the TextBlock, also the Relative Source has Self.

```xml
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="root" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./*}" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="ROOT"
            Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=TestControl}">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu
                cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Add Element"
                        cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action AddElement($datacontext)]" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

**Hierarchical Template for Node**

```xml
<HierarchicalDataTemplate
    DataType="Node"
    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./*}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="Node:" />
        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
            Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=TestControl}"
            Text="{Binding XPath=@name}" >
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu
                    cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Add Element"
                        cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action AddElement($datacontext)]" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

**Output Example,**
For Root

[image]

For Node,
[image]

Comment: First of all - great thanks for you answer, but unfortunally this code seems to be not working. I tried to use it and did not succeed with it. I've got an exception "No target found for method AddElement".  I have a  question - what is "TestControl"? Can you provide a more complete code or some links to githhub for example?

Comment: @whizzzkey "TestControl" is the x:Name of your UserControl. This would help in getting the viewmodel associated with the Control. The other error, Addelement would be related to it, since AddElement for exist in ViewModel, and since TestControl wasn't found, so wasn't viewmodel associated with it. I would add more code,may be in git, but may be by evening as am away from my desk. In meanwhile, if you could add x:Name to your UserControl and test it again, it would be great

Comment: thanks for your help, could you give me a response for this question, please:  you wrote in the first sentence  "TestControl" is the x:Name of your UserControl. What is a UserControl? A whole View i.e. Window or something else? I made a simple app with treeview and caliburn that describes a problem in my post and I've pushed it in git, can you check it and help me to figure it out?? https://github.com/whizzzkey/WpfApp1

Comment: @whizzzkey in case this is a Window, it should be name of Window. I assumed you had create a UserControl. So, in your case, TestControl is the name of your window.

Comment: So I assumed it correctly, I've put  x:Name="TestControl" to Window  but unfortunately my simple app still throws me an error "No target found for method AddElement"

Comment: @whizzzkey Please check the updated code. I have mentioned the modifications needed in your uploaded code.

Comment: I am very grateful to you very much for taking the time to solve my problem. It finally works!!!

Comment: @whizzzkey Glad to help you :)